# Parallell make with multiple yacc parsers

Tags: gnu-make, yacc

I have a project that contains multiple parsers generated using yacc. There are rules for each parser that looks something like:

```
xgram.c xgram.h : xgram.y
    yacc xgram.y
    mv y.tab.c xgram.c
    mv y.tab.h xgram.h
```

If I run this with `make` it works fine since each parser will be generated in sequence.

However, if I run it with `make -j 10` there is an obviously a conflict about the `y.tab.c` file since the commands for each grammar will generate its own `y.tab.h` in parallel.

How can I avoid this? The only thing that I have found and tried is to use `TMPDIR` on each `yacc` command line to make it create the output files in different directories, which did not work.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure that you mis-typed the `mv` commands in your recipe.

If you have `bison`, see the other answer.

If your version of `yacc` is POSIX-compliant it should support the `-b` option, in which case you can use:

```
xgram.c xgram.h : xgram.y
        yacc -b xgram -d xgram.y
        mv xgram.tab.c xgram.c
        mv xgram.tab.h xgram.h
```

If you're not using a POSIX `yacc` you can do a hack like this:

```
xgram.c xgram.h : xgram.y
        mkdir -p tmp_xgram
        (cd tmp_xgram && yacc -d ../xgram.y && mv y.tab.c ../xgram.c && mv y.tab.h ../xgram.h)
        rm -rf tmp_xgram
```

I think that will work.  If it still complains you may have to actually copy `../xgram.y` to the temp directory first...

If you have GNU make 4.3 you can use `xgram.c xgram.h &: xgram.y` to get a more correct rule, rather than `:`

Comment: I've inherited this project. and it probably pre-dates the `-b` option (or the developers were as ignorant about it as I was), but it allows me to get rid of the moving too. I can just change to use the separately generated files as they are.

Comment: what does the gmake extension `&:` mean? It is hard to google for...

Comment: Found the documentation for "grouped rules" in `gmake` here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multiple-Targets.html#Multiple-Targets

Answer (score 1):

Call bison by its name (`bison`), don't use the `-y` flag, and use the `-o` command-line flag:

```
xgram.c xgram.h : xgram.y
    bison -o xgram.c -d xgram.y
```

Comment: This works great... if you're really using `bison`.